# Assign a sprite to a new Image programmatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a struct, InventorySlot, that holds an Image, and an Item class that holds a Sprite. When I click on a specific inventory slot I want to equip that item, but when I try to assign the Sprite to the Image on a new InventorySlot object, it's coming up with a null reference error.

```
public override void Click(Inventory inventory)
{
    var inventorySlot = new InventorySlot();
    inventorySlot.Image.sprite = Item.sprite; // TODO: This line is throwing an exception
    inventorySlot.InventoryItem = this;
    inventory.armourSlot.EquipItem(inventorySlot);
}
```

Is there a way that I can do this?

Comment: If you check the InventorySlot, does Image get default newed? I suspect it is uninitalized (null) which causes the exception when you do slot.Image, alternatively just on the line before you can do slot.Image = new ....

Comment: Yes it is null, and I can't new the Image on the line before because the Image constructor is protected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make a new instance of InventorySlot, it doesn't automatically create the components for the variables inside it. So after initializing inventorySlot, you need to set Image to whatever Image component you want it to use. That way it's not null.

Alternatively, I recommend doing this differently in general.

- Add [System.Serializable] above your InventorySlot struct so that it can be viewed in the inspector.
- Make a list of InventorySlot in this script.
- Assign all the Image references there in inspector.
- Then when you equip an item, instead of creating a whole new InventorySlot, just change the sprite of the appropriate slot from your list.